# When publishing how do I target specific .NET Core Runtimes?

Tags: build, .net-core, runtime-identifier

When I publish my .NET Core app, it outputs a `runtimes` directory with the following sub-directories:

```
- publish/runtimes/
   - debian.8-x64/
   - fedora.23-x64/
   - fedora.24-x64/
   - opensuse.13.2-x64/
   - opensuse.42.1-x64/
   - osx/
   - osx.10.10-x64/
   - rhel.7-x64/
   - ubuntu.14.04-x64/
   - ubuntu.16.04-x64/
   - ubuntu.16.10-x64/
   - unix/
   - win/
```

On my CI/CD server I publish my applications with this command:

```sh
dotnet publish -c Release -o ..\publish
```

My publish settings in the project file are the following:

- Target Framework: netcoreapp2.1
- Deployment Mode: Framework-Dependent
- Target Runtime: win-x64

I only plan to publish this application on Windows 2016 Server so the OSX/Linux/Unix `runtimes` folders are not necessary. Worse in several cases these `runtimes` folders contain known vulnerable `dlls` which lead to false positive OSA scans.

Is there a way to configure the project to only output the `win` runtime folder?

**Update**

I have tried the suggestions by @ahsteele and the output of adding the RIDs to my csproj files is the same as if I did not specify the RIDs.

When I run CI/CD command example

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x86 -o ..\publish
```

I believe it creates a self-contained deployment. As my publish directory goes from being 55MB to 120MB and from 237 files to 482 files.

**Update 2**

I have tried specifying my startup project for the publish step and it builds the run time directories to be more compact.

Here is the build command I am running:

```sh
dotnet publish .\startupProject.csproj -c Release -o ..\publish
```

And this is the output:

```
- publish/runtimes/
   - unix/
   - win/
```

Some of the projects in my solution do specify netstandard2.0 and some specify netcoreapp2.0. Does Microsoft document anywhere that if you don't specify a target framework or a specific csproj file, it will give you all of the target frameworks for all of the possible runtimes?

Comment: Can you share your csproj file? Can you reproduce this with a simpler project (less code, but similar csproj file)? Is there a `RuntimeIdentifiers` setting in your project file?

Comment: @omajid There are no `RuntimeIdentifiers` in any of the project files for the solution. Let me see if I can get something.

Comment: @omajid I tried creating a simple project and it does now show this behavior. I'll keep trying to add complexity to see if I can duplicate this. Thanks!

Comment: Self-contained deployment requires `--self-contained` switch, which you never use.

Comment: @LexLi I modified the command to include the `dotnet publish -c Release -o ..\publish-selfcontained -r win10-x86 --self-contained` and its output is the same as if I did not include the `--self-contained` flag. 482 Files and 120MB.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to specify your runtime with the [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) `-r` switch. From the [.NET Core RID Catalog - Windows RIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#windows-rids) the Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016 RIDs are:

- win10-x64
- win10-x86
- win10-arm
- win10-arm64

Meaning that your CI/CD command can specify the runtime:

```sh
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x86 -o ..\publish
```

Alternatively a single RID can be set in the [`<RuntimeIdentifier>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#runtimeidentifier) element of your project file:

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

Multiple RIDs can be defined as a semicolon-delimited list in the project file's [`<RuntimeIdentifiers>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#runtimeidentifiers) element:

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win10-x86</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding the RIDs to my csproj files and it did not change the output of the runtime directory. I ran the CI/CD command in your example and it doubled the size of the publish directory compared to no RID specified. It removed the runtime directory and looks like it is now a self contained deployment with a lot of Microsoft DLLs.