# How to stop the publishing of FxCop libraries in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, fxcop

A .NET Standard 2.1 library has a package reference to FxCop like so:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.9.5">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

A .NET Core 3.0 app references this Standard library. When I publish the app, several `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` dlls appear in the publish directory. They "shouldn't", but I don't know *why* they shouldn't so therefore I don't know how to tell them to not be there.

[A recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291135/why-is-microsoft-codeanalysis-published-with-asp-net-core-website) from ASP.NET has a similar problem, but I can't glean anything useful from it.

Comment: Apologies, the entire .NET build process is a mystical black box to me. I have trouble researching build problems because I can't find the words to write in the search box.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. You will have to share more information about your project.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the response. The vibe I'm getting is that this is just another enigma of the build system without a solution, or a solution that will manifest when I least expect it. For now I will let the problem the simmer. Thank you!

Comment: The build engine MSBuild and .NET Core CLI are both open sourced, so if you do have a way to reliably reproduce it, open an issue and let Microsoft investigate it https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild