# How to stop the localized Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.*.resources.dll files from getting published by ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

When I publish an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project, I get a few localized folders where the 4 assemblies shown are in each of these folders. I am not sure why these folders and files get included. None of my packages reference a `CodeAnalysis` package.

I added `<PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>` in the csproj file but it didn't help. Is there a way to exclude them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey maybe this can help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58298619/9358386

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Microsoft.CodeAnalysis published with ASP.NET Core website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291135/why-is-microsoft-codeanalysis-published-with-asp-net-core-website)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You get a lot of language folders containing `CodeAnalysis.dll` files in your published output if you have a project reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`, which is needed for scaffolding controllers. If that is true for your project, change the package reference in your `.csproj` file to include `ExcludeAssets="all"`

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" ExcludeAssets="All" />
```

For example, old `*.csproj` file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-foo-4E53EF45-B3BE-4943-81BE-2449DC5AA2BC</UserSecretsId>
    <BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design"
                      Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

New file `*.csproj` should be

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-foo-4E53EF45-B3BE-4943-81BE-2449DC5AA2BC</UserSecretsId>
    <BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design"
                      Version="3.0.0"
                      ExcludeAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hello, my application uses asp net core 3 and I added * .csproj ExcludeAssets = "All", but this did not work. Any other ideas?)

Comment: @al.koval clean and build, or delete bin folder with your release, build again.

Comment: I experience the same issue. I even tried to delete Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design reference completely. I still have this litter in the deployment folder. Deleting bin folder exct. does not help. Doy you have any other idea?

Comment: Had same problem with core 3.1, tried every solution here and still stuck with those folders.

Comment: @CarlVerret Please check my answer, is for ASP .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 46):

Add this:

```xml
<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
```

to the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

As suggested, you can use `none` to exclude all of them:

```xml
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>none</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
```

and taking consideration languages do you want like english and spanish:

```xml
<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en;es</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
```

Works with VS2019 and other versions

### UPDATE 2021/2022:

Still working with Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6

```xml
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This worked for me and you can use "none" to exclude all of them.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, the source of these localized folders was from the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation. It has a dependency on Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.  You can read more about the purpose of the package here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

You cannot just exclude an asset when trying to take advantage of the package. My work-around was to conditionally include the package reference whenever the project is in debug mode.
[image: conditional package reference]

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I then used an #if pre-processor directive to conditionally run the code that enables razor runtime compilation.
[image: pre-processor directive razor runtime compilation]

```
#if DEBUG
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
#else
            services.AddRazorPages();
#endif
```

Please note: You may need to delete your bin folder to see the folders removed after a build. Also, make sure you are building under the correct solution configuration.

I was able to find a Github issue describing this exact scenario, but unfortunately it was never resolved. https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2247

Comment: Doesn't work in VS2019 with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation and services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

Comment: This is a workaround for not specifying which satellite resources you require from dependencies. I'd opt for specifying them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#satelliteresourcelanguages

Comment: @Zimano I posted that answer 2 years ago. See my answer.